# How to define __contains__ in a Python class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, oop

```
class NewClass:

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __contains__(self, item):

        # ???
```

how to write `# ???` to enable:

```
x in list_of_NewClassObject
```

and return `True` or `False`.

Comment: `NewClass.__contains__` **will not** be invoked for `x in list_of_NewClass_object` - you would need to do e.g. `any(x in NewClass_object for NewClass_object in list_of_NewClass_object)` for `NewClass.__contains__` to be useful. See [the data model docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) for further guidance.

Comment: You might want to define [**`__eq__`**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) instead.

Comment: Could you give a [mcve] that actually shows how this should be used? Should e.g. `1 in [NewClass(1)]` be `True`? If so, @PeterWood is correct and you need to implement `__eq__` as e.g. `def __eq__(self, other): return self.a == other`, as that's the method that will be invoked by `list.__contains__`.

Comment: Problem already solved, thank you

Answer (score 2):

As @PeterWood pointed out, you probably want to define [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) instead:

```
class NewClass(object):

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __eq__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, NewClass):
            return self.a == item.a
        return object.__eq__(self, item)

    def __ne__(self, item):
        return not self.__eq__(item)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.a)
```

Example:

```
>>> a = NewClass(1)
>>> b = NewClass(2)
>>> x = NewClass(1)
>>> x in [a, b]
True
```

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I want, and thank you all.

Comment: If you're defining `__eq__` you will also need [**`__hash__`**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) defined if you want to store objects in hashed collections like a `set` or as the keys to a `dict` object. I usually have a common identity function `_key` which I use to implement `__hash__` and `__eq__`.